# QLPreviewController and iOS 3

Tags: iphone, ios, qlpreviewcontroller

Can I use QLPreviewController on a device with iOS 3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this class is only available in iOS 4.0 or higher: http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/QLPreviewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/QLPreviewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), you can see that it is IOS>=4.